# Reading stdout/stderr simultaneously from java.lang.Process with Java 8 CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, java-8, io-redirection

Suppose I have a `java.lang.Process process` object representing a sub-process I want to start from Java. I need to get both `stdout` and `stderr` output from the sub-process combined as a single `String`, and for the purpose of this question, I have chosen to store `stdout` first, followed by `stderr`. Based on my current understanding, I should be reading from them simultaneously. Sounds like a good task for `CompletableFuture`, I presume?

Hence, I have the following code snippets:

**Getting the output**

```
final CompletableFuture<String> output = fromStream(process.getInputStream()).thenCombine(
        fromStream(process.getErrorStream()),
        (stdout, stderr) -> Stream.concat(stdout, stderr).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
// to actually get the result, for example
System.out.println(output.get());
```

**`fromStream()` helper method**

```
public static CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> fromStream(final InputStream stream) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream)).lines();
    });
}
```

Is there a better/nicer Java-8-way of doing this task? I understand there are the [`redirectOutput()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect-) and [`redirectError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError-java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect-) methods from `ProcessBuilder`, but I don't suppose I can use them to redirect to just a `String`?

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder` and use [`redirectErrorStream(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) which will allow you to redirect the error stream to the input stream automatcially

Comment: what not use "redirectErrorStream" and process single stream (o/p stream) ...

Comment: I didn't read the full Javadoc for `ProcessBuilder`, thanks for pointing that method out (which I obviously missed). Does it still make sense to use `CompletableFuture` on the single `stdout` stream just to read it in the background, or am I better off without it?

Comment: @h.j.k. No. Keep it simple. At the most all you need is a Thread.

Comment: Don’t use asynchronous mechanisms if you plan to wait for their results unconditionally. That’s making things complicated without any benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I missed out on the [`redirectErrorStream(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) method that allows me to pipe `stderr` to `stdout` internally, so there's only one stream to deal with. In this case, using a `CompletableFuture` is completely overkill (pun unintended...?) and I'll probably be better off without it.

Comment: redirectErrorStream is not always good, for example:- the output might be an XML, which needs to be parsed. Any error output in the XML output will cause deserialisation failure.